# How can add atribute to css of page on page load event

Tags: html, css

I want to add `background:rgba(226, 93, 141, 0.76)` attribute to `body:after` psuedo-element after my page is loaded.

Here is my html and css :

```
<style runat="server" id="myStyle"  >
body:after{
    position:fixed;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
</style>
```

How can I access to `body:after` element on page load event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                mystyle.InnerHtml = " body:after{ 
position:fixed;
content:'';
 top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
z-index:-1;
background:rgba(226, 93, 141, 0.76)";
            }





<style runat="server" id="myStyle"  >

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class '`loaded`' & add it to body.

```
body:after{
    position:fixed;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-1;
}

body.loaded:after{
    background:rgba(226, 93, 141, 0.76);
}
```

& then use jQuery (Revise as per ***Faiz Ahmed*** suggested):

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('body').addClass('loaded');
});
```